# Ansible - complex loop with conditional and register stdoutput

Tags: ansible, provisioning, libvirt

I have an ansible playbook which creates libvirt guests based on parsed arguments. I am trying to extend the playbook with an extra argument which will allow me to attach guest OS to specidied Virtual network and assign custom mac address written in a file.

The playbook should is invoked like this:

`ansible-playbook -e "CPU=2 MEMORY=1024 VM_STORAGE=/tmp/zz VM_NAME=desktop5 VM_NETWORK=bridge,Isolated2" vm.yml`

as one of the last step I had to create nics and use specific mac addresses which are defined in a file in following format:

```
#NAT#52:54:00:aa:aa:01#desktop1
#bridge#52:54:00:aa:bb:01#desktop1
#Isolated1#52:54:00:aa:cc:01#desktop1
#Isolated2#52:54:00:aa:dd:01#desktop1
```

How to use just ansible playbook features to attach network interfaces based on the specified extra argument -e VM_NETWORK and which determines the mac addresses.

So far I came with following:

```
  - name: Setting up network
  shell: "/bin/grep -e {{ vm_name }} {{ mac_file }} | grep -e {{ item }} | awk -F\"#\" '{print $3}'"
    register: vm_mac
  command: "/usr/bin/virsh attach-interface --domain {{ vm_name }} --type bridge --source 'bridge0' --model virtio --mac {{ vm_mac }} --config"
  when: item == "bridge"
  with_items: 
    - "{{ VM_NETWORK.split(',') }}"
```

but the problem is I cannot have command and shell action in one task??
Should I fetch the mac address by invoking a shell script and then use it in command?

At the moment I have a bash script which executes virsh command in order to attach or detach interfaces but I was wondering if there is a way to do it dynamically in ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you would just have two tasks. The first would get the MAC and register the `vm_mac` variable while the second would *use* that variable.

For what it's worth, your `shell` task can be substantially simplified, so maybe in the end things would look like:

```
- name: Get MAC
  command: >
    awk -F# -vvm_name="{{ vm_name }}" -vvm_network="{{ item }}"
    '$4 == vm_name && $2 == vm_network {print $3}' "{{ mac_file }}"
  register: vm_macs
  with_items: "{{ vm_networks.split(',') }}"
```

For each network, this will print out the MAC address associated with vm_name.  The contents of the vm_macs variable will include the list of results in the `vm_macs.results` key, and each element of this list will include the network name in the `item` key and the MAC address in the `stdout` key:

```
"vm_macs.results": [
    {
        "item": "bridge", 
        "stdout": "52:54:00:aa:bb:01", 
    },
    {
        "item": "Isolated2", 
        "stdout": "52:54:00:aa:dd:01", 
    }
]
```

There's a bunch of other stuff there, too, but this is what we care about.

You could then use that in a subsequent task like this:

```
- name: attach interface
  command: >
    virsh attach-interface
    --domain {{ vm_name }}
    --type bridge
    --source bridge0
    --model virtio
    --mac {{ item.stdout }}
    --config
  when: item.item == "bridge"
  with_items: "{{ vm_macs.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute commands and searching mac_file on localhost, you can use `pipe` lookup (see [more lookups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups) chapter):

```
- name: Setting up network
  command: >
           /usr/bin/virsh
           attach-interface
           --domain {{ vm_name }}
           --type bridge
           --source 'bridge0'
           --model virtio
           --mac {{ vm_mac }}
           --config
  vars:
    vm_mac: "{{ lookup('pipe', grep_cmd) }}"
    grep_cmd: "/bin/grep -e {{ vm_name }} {{ mac_file }} | grep -e {{ item }} | awk -F\"#\" '{print $3}'"
  when: item == "bridge"
  with_items: "{{ VM_NETWORK.split(',') }}"
```

*Note: I didn't test this exact grep_cmd*

This will work only on localhost, because plugins are executed locally.